# Добавление полей заголовка в JavaMail

Tags: java, email, javamail

Пишу программу, которая отправляет письма с помощью JavaMail. Надо сделать так, чтобы отправитель знал открывал получатель письмо или нет.
Знаю, что делается такое через хедер (наверное `X-Confirm-Reading-To`). но не могу понять и найти в интернете как правильно добавить хедер и как проверить статус (было письмо открыто или нет).

Answer (score 1):

Стандартный функционал реализуется с помощью заголовка `Disposition-Notification-To`, содержащий адрес e-mail, на который будет отправлено письмо - уведомление о прочтении. Детали в [RFC3798](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3798).
Надо отметить, что отправка таких уведомлений контроллируется настройками клиентского ПО, используемого для прочтения (или удаления) сообщения, и обычно отключена из соображений конфиденциальности.
Есть и другие способы подтверждения открытия письма пользователем - например, включение в HTML текст письма персонифицированных ссылок на web ресурс, контролируемый отправителем. По факту обращения к такому ресурсу можно судить об успешности доставки сообщения. Такие технологии используются спаммерами и навязчивыми маркетологами, и потому все современные почтовые системы с такими механизмами борются, по крайней мере предупреждая получателя письма о таком поведении содержимого письма.

Comment: "*все современные почтовые системы с такими механизмами борются, по крайней мере предупреждая получателя письма о таком поведении содержимого письма*" - увы, как правило, недолго. Ровно до тех пор, пока пользователь не задолбается от этих уведомлений или ему не надоест вид писем без картинок. И он не разрешит всё это дело раз и навсегда. Как правило, это происходит довольно быстро... Так что из всех методов этот, наверное, самый "достоверный" (понятно, в кавычках)

Comment: @klopp Ну вот Google, например, с недавнего времени показывает картинки, только если ссылка указывает на ресурсы самого Google.

Comment: Кроме гугла есть куча других веб-почт, а кроме веб-почт есть тонны распространённых клиентов, начиная с "большого" аутлука и заканчивая мобильно-планшетными. И если ни один из них (в здравом уме, конечно), не будет высылать reading/delivery confirmation, то с картинками хоть какой-то "шанс" есть :) (но не нужен)